# Passing URL does not output variable with echo

Tags: php, html, variables, url

The link page:

```
<a href="displayProduct.php?productID=<?php'.$pID.'?>">
```

The displayProduct.php page:

```
<?php

echo $_GET["productID"];

?>
```

This is my tester, to see if clicking on the link will pass the data from page 1 to displayProduct page.

It successfully passes the variable in the *'  URL  '* bar but the echo does not display that variable.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an echo and have some weird concatenation.

```
<a href="displayProduct.php?productID=<?php'.$pID.'?>">
```

should be:

```
<a href="displayProduct.php?productID=<?php echo $pID; ?>">
```

Comment: Works fine for me. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5501e6c353f0c8f91c0f292b7b3efdca7d081632.

Comment: I'm getting my data from my database and outputting a list of data via while loop. Is the while loop interfering with it?

Comment: What while loop? Yes, it's possible it is bad data in the database. I suggest you var_dump the data or browse it manually to verify it's correct.

Comment: Before the echo I can pass the unique productID onto the displayProduct page's URL. I assume it's fine, but now with the echo in the link statement, it still doesn't output the variable onto the page.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I used my old way but forgot to see that it was still echoing a string and the variable wasn't treated as a variable... I'll accept your answer as you've been helpful, and also I'm sure your way will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo 'displayProduct.php?productID=' . $pID; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way:

```
<a href="displayProduct.php?productID=<?php echo $pID ?>">
```